# find (and remove) member from all GitLab projects (that I own)

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to search all GitLab groups and associated projects (that I own or administer) for a specific user (with the intent of removing that user)?  I know how if they are a member of the group itself, but if the group has many projects and some projects have users added individually, then it's tedious to search each project one-by-one.

Answer (score 11):

I have not found such functionality in GitLab UI, so I developed python script using [GitLab API](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/).

Here is the link to repo with source code of my script and docs: https://gitlab.com/CVisionLab/gitlab-tools/

Just download the `gitlab-delete-members.py` script and run in bash command line. Usage example:

```
$ gitlab-delete-members.py --query johndoe123 --token Abcdefg123
 Auth at https://gitlab.com
Project "MyGroupSpam / my-project-foo" (id=11111111) : no users to delete
Project "MyGroupSpam / my-project-bar" (id=11111112) : delete johndoe123 (id=3333333) :  ok
Project "NotMyGroupEggs / not-my-project-baz" (id=11111113) : delete johndoe123 (id=3333333) :  fail
 1 members deleted in 2 repositories
```

Just in case I provide full source of the script here:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Handy script for searching and deleting members from Gitlab projects.
Built on top of GitLab Python API: https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/
"""

import argparse
import gitlab


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Delete member from all accessible gitlab projects.')
    parser.add_argument('--query', required=True,
                        help='Gitlab query string that defines users '
                        'to be deleted (username is recommended)')
    parser.add_argument('--token', required=True,
                        help='Gitlab token of your user')
    parser.add_argument('--url', default='https://gitlab.com',
                        help='Gitlab URL')
    parser.add_argument('--visibility', default='private',
                        help='Gitlab projects visibility')
    parser.add_argument('--dry', action='store_true',
                        help='dry run')
    return parser.parse_args()


def print_ok():
    print(' ok')


def print_fail():
    print(' fail')


def print_skip():
    print(' skip')


def main():
    # Greeting and args parsing.
    args = parse_args()

    # Initialize Gitlab API.
    print(f' Auth to {args.url} : ', end='')
    gl = gitlab.Gitlab(args.url, private_token=args.token)
    try:
        gl.auth()
        print_ok()
    except:  # noqa
        print_fail()
        return

    # Iterate over projects.
    projects = gl.projects.list(all=True, visibility=args.visibility)
    del_members_count = 0
    del_projects_count = 0
    for p in projects:
        print(f'Project "{p.name_with_namespace}" (id={p.id}) :',
              end='')

        # Query members.
        members = p.members.list(query=args.query)

        # Delete members.
        if len(members) == 0:
            print(' no users to delete')
        else:
            del_projects_count += 1
            for m in members:
                print(f' delete {m.username} (id={m.id}) : ', end='')
                if not args.dry:
                    try:
                        m.delete()
                        print_ok()
                        del_members_count += 1
                    except:  # noqa
                        print_fail()
                else:
                    print_skip()

    # Statistics.
    print(f' {del_members_count} members deleted '
          f'in {del_projects_count} repositories')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want to know which GitLab API functions are used, here is the short list:

- `gl = gitlab.Gitlab(...)` – create API object
- `gl.auth()` - authenticate
- `projects = gl.projects.list(...)` - get list of projects
- `members = p.members.list(...)` - list members of the certain project that matches query
- `m.delete()` - delete member from project

Comment: does this also check the permission given on groups that i own?

Comment: @efraim Unfortunately no. I know this issue but had no time to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

> if the group has many projects and some projects have users added individually, then it's tedious to search each project one-by-one.

Yet, this would be the one option, considering it is easy to script:

- The [Groups API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/groups.html) can [list projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/groups.html#list-a-group-s-projects) (a bit as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sbz/11208130))
- The [Projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html) can [list users](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-user-projects)

If you are an admin, you can also [lists the project of a User](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#list-user-projects)

Removing a user from a project through API was [requested in issue 7687](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/7687) and [resolved in GitLAb 8.7](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/3613).

```
DEL /projects/#{project.id}/members/#{user.id}
```

Comment: AFAIK, listing user projects with https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#list-user-projects works only for project owned by the user, not where he's just a member.

Comment: @Pixou Yes (or it ouwld list only public projects: "When accessed without authentication, only public projects are returned.") So it won't work for private projects indeed.